# conversion from c++ with opengl code to QT application with GUI?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have written a program in C++ (object oriented) I used OpenGL in order to render something in 
screen. I also used microsoft kinect SDK for windows , now I want to make a GUI for my program to make it more like application with Menus, buttons 
etc. I want to know is it possible to convert my program in a way I said to QT? what kind of changes are necessary ?  because I don't know a lot about QT, any help ?

Comment: Well, if you currently are displaying via OpenGL, and do not want to have that in your new application, you have to start from scratch.

Comment: I want to have opengl in new one too.

Comment: You can use Qt's OpenGL module: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtopengl.html This will probably require refactoring of your program.

Comment: don't know if this is useful at all, but using qt together with VTK works pretty well...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Qt is very OpenGL and C++ friendly. (It's written in C++ and even has a QGLWidget component). Plus has all the menus and buttons, etc. needed for general GUI programming.

I would recommend starting with a working Qt OpenGL app - a small one - and adding your OpenGL code.

This one: [Hello GL](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/opengl-hellogl.html)

Comment: what about kinect? it will work well or need to modify either or what ?

Comment: I don't know much about Kinect, if it's a C++ code base, I don't see any reason you can't continue to use it along with Qt. You may be limited to Windows though, MS isn't too interested in other OSes. (I found a Kinect project using Qt here: https://github.com/ttvd/kinect).

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do OpenGL in Qt. Some better materials is the NeHe implementation in Qt.

http://qt-project.org/wiki/NeHe_in_Qt

After reading some blogs and examples from above wiki page, I think you could find out how to use OpenGL in Qt world. I will not copy them to here, ^_^.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

It will be difficult, and quite a bit of work but you can integrate OpenGL into Qt. The main issue will be difference in the more powerful Qt model (and it comes with buttons, windows, and a lot of triggers that make things easier)

You may have some work cut out to get the Qt base. I would recommend something along the lines of http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt4/tutorials-addressbook.html as a starting place. This tutorial is for a more complex app than just a simple hello world and might get you started easier.